# Does anyone knows the difference between the two lines below?

Tags: pytorch

I read the codes in pytorch tutorial resently and I find a interesting thing below:

```
model_conv = torchvision.models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
for param in model_conv.parameters(): **# 1**
    param.requires_grad = False       **# 1**

# Parameters of newly constructed modules have requires_grad=True by default
num_ftrs = model_conv.fc.in_features
model_conv.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 2)

model_conv = model_conv.to(device)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Observe that only parameters of final layer are being optimized as
# opposed to before.
optimizer_conv = optim.SGD(model_conv.fc.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9) **# 2**

# Decay LR by a factor of 0.1 every 7 epochs
exp_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer_conv, step_size=7, gamma=0.1)`
```

I just wonder what's the difference between # 1 and # 2,
if I set #1, Can I just set #2 to code like this?:
optimizer_ft = optim.SGD(model_ft.parameters(), lr=1e-3, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.1)
or if I just delete # 1 and leave # 2 alone?

I just wonder what is the difference between #1 and #2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you set #1 the code for #2 could go like this `optimizer_ft = optim.SGD(model_ft.parameters(), lr=1e-3, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.1)` it will automatically get which parameters to set gradient True for.
See here: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/finetuning_torchvision_models_tutorial.html

> This helper function sets the .requires_grad attribute of the
> parameters in the model to False when we are feature extracting. By
> default, when we load a pretrained model all of the parameters have
> .requires_grad=True, which is fine if we are training from scratch or
> finetuning. However, if we are feature extracting and only want to
> compute gradients for the newly initialized layer then we want all of
> the other parameters to not require gradients. This will make more
> sense later.
>
> ```
> def set_parameter_requires_grad(model, feature_extracting):
>      if feature_extracting:
>          for param in model.parameters():
>              param.requires_grad = False
> ```

For

> if I just delete # 1 and leave # 2 alone?

You could do that too but imagine if you had to finetune multiple layers in that case it would be redundant to use `model_conv.new_layer.parameters()` for every new layer so the first way that you said and used seems a better way to do it in that case.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Seemly I just get the difference between tensor.requires_grad(False) and "model.parameters()" from the optim.SGD(model_ft.parameters(), lr=1e-3, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.1):tensor.requires_grad(False) means I don't want to compute the gradient of the tensor, and model.parameters() means which parameters I need to apply SGD no matter whether the gradient is computed. Am I right?

Comment: `model.parameters()` just supply the parameters of the model to SGD optimizer and only those parameters will be updated where `requires_grad` is set to True